# Using Python functions within Excel

Tags: python, excel

I've been searching for the best way to use Python functions within excel/VBA. I tried pyxll for a month (their free trial), but I found it very unreliable.

I've found now three other possibilities: ExcelPython, DataNitro and xlwings. Any suggestions? Which one is the most widely used in the Python community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have settled on xlwings for right now. I had to go through the following steps to get xlwings setup, maybe it'll help someone else down the road to have a more clear roadmap of needed items.

**Process for my setup to get XLWINGS running**

1. Python 3.4

   MS C++ 2010

   Pywin32

   pip install xlwings